# I am using Arduino stepper motor and pir sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

my project about automated system I am using stepper motor to open and close the gate but my point is I want my code be like when the gate opened it stays 5 seconds then check the sensor if there is a motion the gate should not close and stay open when there is no motion the gate should close and if the gate is closing and there is a motion , motion should interrupt closing the gate and reopening the gate I am using Arduino uno

the code is :

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>//include radioHead ASK library 
#include <SPI.h> // include dependant SPI libray
#include <Stepper.h> // Include the Arduino Stepper.h library:
// Define number of steps per rotation:

RH_ASK rf_driver; // create ASK object
int ledon = 13;
int ledoff = 5;
int sensor = 3;

const int stepsPerRevolution = 2048;// Define number of steps per rotation:


// Wiring:
// Pin 8 to IN1 on the ULN2003 driver
// Pin 9 to IN2 on the ULN2003 driver
// Pin 10 to IN3 on the ULN2003 driver
// Pin 11 to IN4 on the ULN2003 driver
// Create stepper object called 'myStepper', note the pin order:
Stepper myStepper = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 10, 9, 11);



void setup() {

  rf_driver.init(); //initialize ASK object

  // Begin Serial communication at a baud rate of 9600:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Set the speed to 5 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(5);
  pinMode(ledon, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledoff, OUTPUT);



}


void loop() {

  //set buffer to size of expected message
  //uint8_t buf[8];
  // uint8_t buflen =sizeof(buf);

  //check if recevied packet is correct size
  //  if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))
  //{
  // int i;
  // message received with valid checksum
  // Serial.print("id: ");
  // Serial.println((char*)buf);
  // String userid =(char*)buf;
  // Serial.println(userid);

  // }

  //delay(5000);

  // uint8_t buf2[8];
  // uint8_t buflen2 = sizeof(buf2);

  // if (rf_driver.recv(buf,&buflen))

  // {

  //  int i;
  // message received with valid checksum
  // Serial.print("password: ");
  // Serial.println((char*)buf);
  // String password = (char*)buf;
  //  Serial.println(password);

  // }
  // delay(5000);


  String pass = "1234";
  String id = "A00036757";



  if (pass == "1234" ) {
    Serial.print("car exists");
    digitalWrite(ledon, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 3); //clockwise -OPEN GATE
    delay(10000);

    //if(digitalRead(sensor) == HIGH){
    delay(500);
  }

  if (digitalRead(sensor) == LOW) {

    digitalWrite(ledon, LOW);
    delay(300);

    digitalWrite(ledoff, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution / 3); // CLOSE AFTER 5s COUNTERCLOCKWISE -  close gate
    digitalWrite(ledoff, LOW);
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("NO CAR");
  }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Motion sensor's operation depends on the sensor's setting. See [motion sensor setting](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-motion-sensor#content_advanced_uses). Please post your sensor's setting